Python CLI/Package to handle DTM conversion from raster to mesh (obj or ply)
I was wondering if there is a Python CLI, package or even a QGIS tool that makes it possible to convert a DEM from raster to mesh. The only way I found at the moment is sampling points from the raster, then interpolating a TIN using QGIS tools. The output .ply file is unreadable (when opening it in MeshLab for instance, I get the following error : "Syntax error on header").

STL anyway...https://github.com/cvr/dem2stl

Found python bindings of a c++ utility that does the job : https://github.com/kylebarron/pydelatin
